# TSP in CPLEX Studio

Tags: cplex

what is the dist array, and how do I fill it out for the next cost matrix?

[ 99 2 3 4 1
2 99 5 6 3
3 5 99 7 2
4 6 2 99 6
1 3 1 6 99 ]

I used the standard cplex solution

.mod:

```
int     n       = ...;
range   Cities  = 1..n;

tuple       edge {
    int i;
    int j;
}

setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in Cities};
int     dist[Edges] = ...;
 
dvar boolean x[Edges];
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in Cities};
int     dist[Edges] = ...;
```

you expect to get a symmetrical matrix with only half of the (i,j) but in

```
[ 99 2 3 4 1 2 99 5 6 3 3 5 99 7 2 4 6 2 99 6 1 3 1 6 99 ]
```

you have provided the full 5*5 array.

So in your model you should change

```
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in Cities};
```

into

```
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | i,j in Cities};
```